# Slow High Sierra after restore from Time Capsule

Tags: backup, time-machine, ssd, restore, time-capsule

So I had a hard drive (SSD) failure some time ago (it lasted 5 years of intense use, so I kinda expected that to happen).
Luckily I had my Time Capsule running all the time, so it was a no brainer to buy a new SSD for my Macbook Air and restore it.

However after restore I found out that my laptop wasn't quite as fast as it used to be, moreover I'd get frequent freezes & beach-balling that would last up to 20 seconds. Needless to say, I was quite concerned - I was running many system diagnostics, tried cleaning it up, did SMC & PRAM reset, but nothing seemed to help much.

What was the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that my system restored in the old "MacOS Extended" file system. You can check yours by right-clicking your hard drive in Finder sidebar pane and choosing "Get Info". The correct entry for High Sierra should be APFS, like on the picture below:

[image: Correct file system]

So in case your restore left you with an older file system, you need to reinstall MacOS from the App Store. Unluckily I don't remember the exact details how I made the installer go through the installation again, but I managed to do this by finding the installer in Applications folder - without starting from the recovery partition (which would probably try to clean install my OS).
I hope that helps someone!